# can i use the same control variable for interaction?

Tags: regression, interaction

My research question is: how does democracy affect infant mortality rate?

I have controlled for confounders such as GDP per capita etc

in this case, when run interactive model, can i use GDP per capita again as a interaction?

thanks

Comment: The question seems to be quite vague. Are you asking if you can fit an interaction term like: $IMR_i=\beta_0+\beta_1Democracy+\beta_2GDP+\beta_3Democracy:GDP+\epsilon_i$ ? If so, then you potentially can, but more information would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In my model, I have 3 control variables: GDP per capita, political globalization and economic globalisation.

I also need to include a interaction model. I am thinking using GDP per capita as interactive variable. In this case, do I need to keep the other two control variables (political and eco globalization) in the model: IMR=b0+b1democracy+b2gdp percapita+b3democracy\*gdp per capita+b4political global+b5economic globalisation

or can I simply ignore them like: IMR=b0+b1democracy+b2gdp percapita+b3democracy\*gdp per capita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First your choice of the word "affects" is a little problematic as it is causal and you are clearly doing an observational study here.  "Is related to" would be better.

To your actual question: If you are investigating the interaction of two variables then, in nearly all cases, you will definitely want to include both main effects in your regression. GDP by itself can't be an interaction - interactions have to involve at least two variables.